# how do you reassign global variables in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, variables, global-variables

I am currently attempting to run a Python code that has this basic structure:

```
    var = 0
    def Function2():
        if var == 1:
            ...   
    def Function():
        var = 1
        Function2()
```

However, when it runs, it doesn't recognize the global variable. Is there any way to fix this?

Comment: Shot version: You can read global variables from everywhere, but in order to modify them in a function you need to use the `global` keyword on it first.

Answer (score 3):

Did you try to write global before the variable name? for example:

```
a = "Hello"


def change_a():
   global a
   a = "Good"


print(a)
```

In this mode i've change the content of a from "Hello" to "Good"